# Android Firebase OnCompleteListener not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a code where I want to save some data in Firebase database. The database reference is `databasereference` and unique is `databasereference.push()`.
The problem is the code seems to work until the `OnCompleteListener`. Then it seems to stop.

The code is:

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String name = dataSnapshot.child("firstname").getValue().toString() + " " + dataSnapshot.child("lastname").getValue().toString();
        unique.child("name").setValue(name).addOnCompleteListener(
            new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        unique.child("UserId").setValue(userId);
                        int ts = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
                        unique.child("time").setValue(0-ts);
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Here the database is only storing child `name`. If we modify the code like this:

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String name = dataSnapshot.child("firstname").getValue().toString() + " " + dataSnapshot.child("lastname").getValue().toString();
        unique.child("UserId").setValue(userId);
        int ts = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
        unique.child("time").setValue(0-ts);
        unique.child("name").setValue(name).addOnCompleteListener(
            new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        unique.child("somethingElse").setValue("something else");

                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

In this case it stores `userId`, `time`, `name` but not the `somethingElse`.

Comment: kindly add database image

Comment: You should add a message to see if your listener is called, also you may be getting an error (add log for the case where the task is not successful).

Comment: Maybe `task.isSuccessful()` returns `false`? Did you check it?

Comment: Sorry for late response. I just checked it. It doesnt even go to the if(task.is...) part.

Comment: `databaseReference` and `unique` references please add it in the question